# key 1.0 must not contain '.' error in MongoDB Compass

Tags: database, mongodb, shell, mongodb-compass

I am trying to insert the following document in a collection inside a mongo database using MongoDB Compass.

```
{
   "name":"cat",
   "label":{
      "1.0":"foo",
      "2.0":"bar"
   }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

> key 1.0 must not contain '.'

I tried to insert the same document via mongo shell with the command:

```
db.collection_name.insert([
    {
        "name": "cat",
        "label": {
            "1.0": "foo",
            "2.0": "bar"
    }

]);
```

and the document is inserted correctly.

Also, if I export the whole collection with MongoDB Compass and then I try to import it, I got the error.

So, my question is: why MongoDB Compass gives me that error while the `insert` command via terminal works correctly?

I have the latest version of MongoDB Compass installed (1.20.4 Stable)